# Is it obligatory to do annotation for __init__?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, pep8, python-typing

PEP8 states that the annotation for returning `__init__` must be `None`. Am I obligated to do this in terms of code style? Will my code look wrong if I do annotations everywhere, omitting `__init__`?

Answer (score 0):

From [PEP 484 - Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals), under the **Rationale and Goals** section, the **Non-goals** subsection reads:

> It should also be emphasized that **Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.**

You do not have to include annotations if you do not want to. That said, if you intend on including annotations everywhere, omitting them for `__init__` may look out of place.

From the intro of [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds),

> [...] Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.

Comment: To paraphrase.  It doesn't matter.  But be consistent with yourself and with already existing code.